# Google analytics.js not working but analytics_debug.js does

Tags: google-analytics

recently I stopped receiving data in google analytics as if the tracking code were missing. I made many attempts to understand what was happening and analytics.js seemed to load properly and more over after it initialized I logged in the console the global function that had initialized and was as expected. Trying to figure out what is happening I switched to analytics_debug.js and everything worked great without changing anything else. For now I have left it to analytics_debug.js but that can't be permanent , is there any obvious reason for why  analytics_debug.js is working as expected but  analytics.js doesn't ? Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: Can you post your code. It is hard to guess what's wrong without seeing how you have it implemented.

Answer (score 0):

After tearing apart all the front end JS app , I figured out that another tracker needed to be initialized in the global variable sa so it had to have:

```
var sa = null;
```

but google analytics.js (interesting enough not analytics_debug.js) doesn't work if there is a global variable sa. Deleting this solved the issue (that another tracker haven't been used by this web app but the code was there because it would in the near feature , since then I have learned that their changed their instructions (again with a predefined global variable) but at least not with sa). I couldn't suspect that analytics.js has to do with global variables expect the one you instruct it as the global function name, other than that I still can't understand why this is the case , but removing that global solved it